# Rails 4 Display data from multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I know this is easy but I can't get it working.  I am creating a site where users can create posts. I want to show those posts along with the user name, which is contained in the user table.  I can't get it showing!  I get this error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is my code:

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts\

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

Controllers:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.includes(:user).all.sort_by &:created_at
    @posts.reverse!
  end

class UsersController < ApplicationController 
  def index
    @users = User.all.order(:name)
  end
```

View:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.user.name %><BR><BR>
  <%= post.post_content %><BR><BR>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What do you get when you do `Post.includes(:user).all.sort_by(&:created_at).first` and `Post.includes(:user).all.sort_by(&:created_at).first.user.name` in the rails console?

Comment: If your objects are actually related, then you wouldn't need to include user. `Post.first.user` should return a user object. It looks like it's returning nil for you, so your association wasn't saved.

Comment: It could be because there is a post record in your db that has not been assigned to any user. run this query in `rails console` to see if there are any:  `Post.where(user_id: nil)`

Comment: for the first one I get the first post, for the second one I get the name of the poster. @nikkon226

Comment: @Alireza, It didn't return anything.

Comment: @MandyM, Can you please add a backtrace for the exception?

Comment: @prcu, here are the top 3 they are the only files I touched but I can post the whole list if you want.  

app/views/posts/index.html.erb:8:in `block in _app_views_posts_index_html_erb___4377902033383230034_70338029361680'

app/views/posts/index.html.erb:6:in `each'

app/views/posts/index.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_posts_index_html_erb___4377902033383230034_70338029361680'

Comment: You can replace current output with `<%= [@post.id, @post.user_id, @post.user.try!(:id)].inspect %>` to check it one last time. You can find post that fails.

Comment: @prcu I tried that, I got the following error:  undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

before, i was able to print a list of posts with their post_id and user_id info so not sure why id is nil.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, `post` instead of `@post`.

Comment: @prcu I get this: [151, 53, 53] which is post_id/user_id/user_id.  Thanks!

Comment: So there should be record where last element is `nil`, it's a cause of errors.

Comment: THANK YOU! the user ID was 0 so it didn't show up in the search for nil above.  What a pain!  I just did a quick SQL delete statement and all is well!

Comment: Anyway if you don't use foreign keys you should use `.try!` in every such place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's allowed to add post without user in your application. So you can replace it with `post.user.try!(:name)`.

P.S. You should better use `.order(:created_at)` instead of `sort_by(&:created_at)`.

Comment: Missed it. You can use `.order(created_at: :desc)` and also remove `.reverse!`.

Comment: I just checked. all of my posts have associated users and all of my users have names.